# pass python lists tp methods

Tags: python, list, methods

I want to read a file and create a list from one of its columns by split() method and pass on this list to another method. Can someone explain what is the most pythonic way to achieve that ??

```
def t(fname):
     k = []
     with open(fname, 'rU') as tx:
         for line in tx:
             lin = line.split()
             k.append(lin[1])
             res = anno(k)
             for id in res.items():
                  if i > 0.05:
                      print(i)
```

I want to pass elements of 'k' as one list to anno() method. But in this way, I have number of lists but not one (required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of appending to that list one by one why don't you just have a loop for that particular statement like `k = [(line.split())[1] for line in tx]`.

And instead of using `with open(file) as:` I have used `tx = open(file)` so whenever you have it's need you can use it and close it using tx.close() , it eliminate that that extra level of intendation.

```
def t(fname):
   k = []
   tx = open(fname, 'rU')
   k = [(line.split())[1] for line in tx]
   tx.close()
   res = anno(k)
   for i in res.items():
       if i > 0.05:print(i)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @jadsq Done. Yes, I will keep that in mind in future answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a new list, lsit comprehensions ate the prefered way:

```
def t(fname):
 with open(fname, 'rU') as tx:
     k = [(line.split())[1] for line in tx]
     res = anno(k)
     for i in res.items():
         if i > 0.05:
             print(i)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use  `(line.split())[1]` instead of `line.split()[1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just did a mistake with the nesting. You have to call `anno()` after you've build the list, outside the for loop.

```
def t(fname):
    k = []
    for line in open('fname'):
        k.append(line.split()[1])
    res = anno(k)
```